# Remove all the rows of handson table

Tags: handsontable

I am new to handsontable.
My handsontable rows are readonly.
I wanted to remove all rows of handsontable on a button click.

Please help me.

Comment: show what you already tried

Answer (score 4):

Do update with empty dataset:

```
handsontableInstance.updateSettings({
    data : []
});
```

This removes all rows (and leave header if there is some).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to "remove" all rows. For example, one, and the easiest, would be to empty your data array. So say that you initialized your HOT instance with the `data` field as array `dataArray`. Your button would only need do:

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() { dataArray = [];})
```

That would be the easiest way but of course you'd be bypassing HOT. This means that if your application gets more complex and you rely on handlers such as `afterRemoveRow`, then this method will bypass them. In this latter case, you'd want to use the hot.alter() method as follows:

```
hot.alter('remove_row', 0); // would remove the row at index 0;
```

With this I am assuming you know how to use a for loop that could iterate through all rows and remove them, one by one. An expensive operation but it would ensure all the proper handlers get called.

Answer (score 0):

`tableInstance.clear()`
Clears the data from the table (the table settings remain intact).
refer to the
[doc](https://handsontable.com/docs/api/core/#clear)